# message.guilds.fetchAuditLogs is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I recently updated my bot from discordjs v13 to v14, everything works so far except for reading/fetching auditlogs

My Test-Code

```
module.exports = async (client, message) => {
    if (!message.guilds) return;
    console.log(message.guilds)
    
        console.log("1")
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
        console.log("2")
         const fetchedLogs = await message.guilds.fetchAuditLogs( {
            limit: 6,
            type: 'MESSAGE_DELETE'
        } ) 
        console.log("3")
        console.log(fetchedLogs)
    }
```

With discordv13 my "logger" for the deleted messages worked without problems, but since discordv14 i get this error:

When I use message.guilds:

> message.guilds.fetchAuditLogs is not a function

When I use message.guild:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetchAuditLogs')

According to documentation `message.guild.fetchAuditLogs()`
would be the correct way to do it but message.guild returned "`undefined`" while `message.guilds` returned the `GuildManager()`

Comment: If `message.guild` is `undefined` then it means that there is no `guild` in `message`
There can be 2 reasons: 
1. the `message` is not in a guild
2. `message` is not defined properly
please tell me what is the code of
is it a command or event or what?

Comment: It's the messageDelete event

Comment: Did you mean `message.guild` instead of `message.guilds`? A message can be long to 1 guild

Comment: The bot is only in one guild.
message.guild returned but always only undefined while message.guilds works

Comment: Sounds like your message and client arguments are mixed up